# How can I fail during an init?

Tags: swift, swift5

I am trying to create this class:

```
class CaptureVideoDataOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

  private let imageCaptureModel: ImageCaptureModel

  override init() {
    super.init()
  }
  
  convenience init?(imageCaptureModel:ImageCaptureModel) {
    self.imageCaptureModel = imageCaptureModel
    
    let queueID = "\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!).captureDeviceOutput"
    let captureVideoDataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: queueID,
                                                    attributes: DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent)
    
    let captureVideoDataOutput = CaptureVideoDataOutput()
    captureVideoDataOutput.videoSettings = videoSettingsParameter
    captureVideoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(captureVideoDataOutput, queue: captureVideoDataOutputQueue)
    
    guard
      imageCaptureModel.captureSession.canAddOutput(captureVideoDataOutput) else {
      return nil
    }
    self = captureVideoDataOutput
  }
```

the idea is the user just using the convenience init and receive a nil if the whole thing fails on the guard or receive the object if it succeeds.

But this code is failing on the first line with

```
let' property 'imageCaptureModel' may not be initialized directly; use "self.init(...)" or "self = ..." instead
```

and on the last line with

```
Cannot assign to value: 'self' is immutable
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an additional (private) initializer for `CaptureVideoDataOutput` that takes ImageCaptureModel and call it in the convenience initializer instead of `CaptureVideoDataOutput()`:

```
  private init(_ model: ImageCaptureModel) {
    self.imageCaptureModel = model
    super.init()
  }

  convenience init?(imageCaptureModel:ImageCaptureModel) {
    let queueID = "\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!).captureDeviceOutput"
    let captureVideoDataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: queueID,
                                                    attributes: DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent)

    self.init(imageCaptureModel)
    videoSettings = videoSettingsParameter
    setSampleBufferDelegate(captureVideoDataOutput, queue: captureVideoDataOutputQueue)

    guard
      imageCaptureModel.captureSession.canAddOutput(captureVideoDataOutput) else {
      return nil
    }
  }
```

Note that also non-convenience initializers may return nil, so I'm not sure why you chose this setup. Consider this:

```
init?(model: ImageCaptureModel) {
    self.imageCaptureModel = model
    let queueID = "\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!).captureDeviceOutput"
    let captureVideoDataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: queueID,
                                                    attributes: DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent)

    super.init()
    videoSettings = videoSettingsParameter
    setSampleBufferDelegate(captureVideoDataOutput, queue: captureVideoDataOutputQueue)

    guard
        imageCaptureModel.captureSession.canAddOutput(captureVideoDataOutput) else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. Can you tell me how would you do it?

Comment: @Duck What do you mean? My answer contains an example already?

Comment: you said "I'm not sure why you chose this setup"

Comment: @Duck Oh, I see. I've added an example. Hopefully that gives you an idea. Since your example is not really complete, I can only guess, but I assume this should work.

Comment: I see, thanks. I have to digest that before I can understand the difference. Thanks.